# Вывод текста во втором окне при нажатии кнопки в первом окне

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Помогите пожалуйста сделать так, чтобы текст выводился не в окне в, котором была кнопка, а в окне, которое создаётся.
Я новичёк, и только изучаю *Tkinter*.

[image: Skreen1]

```
from tkinter import * 
from re 
import T 
import tkinter as tk 
import tkinter.ttk as ttk 
import time 
from tkinter import * 

tab1 = tk.Tk()

def lol2():
    vvz = Tk()
    tet = Text(width=50, height=10)
    tet.pack()
    tet.insert(1.0, '!Перед использованием\n биндов, убедитесь что\n вы включили Eng раскладку!\nТемы:\n    Ctrl+b = Тёмная тема\n   
Ctrl+l = Класическая тема\n    Ctrl+r = Красная тема')
    tet.pack(vvz)
    tet = (vvz)
    vvz.mainloop() 

btn = tk.Button(tab1, text="Binds") 
btn.config(command=lol2) 
btn.place(x=0, y=0) 
tab1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as tk 


tab1 = tk.Tk()

def lol2():
    vvz = Tk()

#    tet = Text(width=50, height=10)
# +++          vvvv
    tet = Text(vvz, width=50, height=10, bg="black", fg="white")                            # !!!

    tet.pack()
    tet.insert(
        1.0, 
        '!Перед использованием\n биндов, убедитесь что\n вы включили Eng раскладку!\nТемы:'
        '\n    Ctrl+b = Тёмная тема'   
        '\n    Ctrl+l = Класическая тема\n    Ctrl+r = Красная тема'
    )
# ???    tet.pack(vvz)
# ???    tet = (vvz)
    tet.pack()
    vvz.mainloop() 

    
btn = tk.Button(tab1, text="Binds") 
btn.config(command=lol2) 
btn.place(x=0, y=0) 
tab1.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]